# This really annoying freezing 17.10 Ubuntu switching user session!

Tags: keyboard, xorg, display, 17.10, input

I've seen several issues about freezing Ubuntu 17.10 GUI.
I am facing this issue, too. It's really annoyng, but I believe my issue is more "accurated".

My computer has two RADEON GPUs, with three monitors.
It's autologged by my wife'sdmseg account.

Funny is when I switch to my account. This Ubuntu release doesn't like to deal with two logged accounts. Because, while one account is active, the other freezes.

For example, I arrive home and login at 16:05. I work for about 30 minutes. When my wife needs to work and we switch session, the clock at her session is showing 16:05! Frozen. Just the mouse moves on, nothing more. Sometimes, session is unlocked, and everything goes normal. But sometimes, the only solution is:

```
sudo pkill -u <username> -KILL
```

Here is dmesg -T output:

```
[qui nov 30 18:24:20 2017] rfkill: input handler enabled
[qui nov 30 18:24:37 2017] rfkill: input handler disabled
[qui nov 30 18:47:32 2017] kauditd_printk_skb: 58 callbacks suppressed
[qui nov 30 18:47:32 2017] audit: type=1400 audit(1512078451.812:70): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=24651 comm="apparmor_parser"
[qui nov 30 18:47:32 2017] audit: type=1400 audit(1512078451.838:71): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper" pid=24651 comm="apparmor_parser"
[qui nov 30 18:47:32 2017] audit: type=1400 audit(1512078451.838:72): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//snap_update_ns" pid=24651 comm="apparmor_parser"
[qui nov 30 19:06:58 2017] rfkill: input handler enabled
[qui nov 30 19:07:10 2017] rfkill: input handler disabled
[qui nov 30 19:08:00 2017] rfkill: input handler enabled
[qui nov 30 19:08:00 2017] rfkill: input handler disabled
[qui nov 30 19:08:34 2017] rfkill: input handler enabled
[qui nov 30 19:08:52 2017] rfkill: input handler disabled
[qui nov 30 20:42:55 2017] rfkill: input handler enabled
[qui nov 30 20:43:05 2017] rfkill: input handler disabled
[qui nov 30 20:59:45 2017] rfkill: input handler enabled
[qui nov 30 20:59:55 2017] rfkill: input handler disabled
[qui nov 30 20:59:57 2017] rfkill: input handler enabled
[qui nov 30 20:59:57 2017] rfkill: input handler disabled
[qui nov 30 21:01:54 2017] rfkill: input handler enabled
[qui nov 30 21:02:00 2017] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

Now, /var/log/syslog output:

```
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (**) Option "fd" "37"
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) event1  - (II) Power Button: (II) device removed
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (**) Option "fd" "92"
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) event0  - (II) Power Button: (II) device removed
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (**) Option "fd" "79"
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) event2  - (II) HID 0566:3032: (II) device removed
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (**) Option "fd" "101"
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (**) Option "fd" "94"
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) event4  - (II) USB OPTICAL MOUSE : (II) device removed
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (**) Option "fd" "101"
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) event3  - (II) HID 0566:3032: (II) device removed
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:1
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:0
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19378]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:67
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:66
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 226:1
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:68
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 226:0
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 5906
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz eP)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x400"x70.0   23.35  640 656 720 800  400 401 404 417 -hsync +vsync (29.2 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x72.0   78.43  1024 1080 1192 1360  768 769 772 801 -hsync +vsync (57.7 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event2  - (II) HID 0566:3032: (II) is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event2  - (II) HID 0566:3032: (II) device is a keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event3  - (II) HID 0566:3032: (II) is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event3  - (II) HID 0566:3032: (II) device is a keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event4  - (II) USB OPTICAL MOUSE : (II) is tagged by udev as: Mouse
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event4  - (II) USB OPTICAL MOUSE : (II) device is a pointer
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:65
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event1  - (II) Power Button: (II) is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event1  - (II) Power Button: (II) device is a keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:64
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event0  - (II) Power Button: (II) is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event0  - (II) Power Button: (II) device is a keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio gsd-rfkill[19708]: g_object_notify: object class 'CcRfkillGlib' has no property named 'kernel-noinput'
Nov 30 21:06:49 olimpio kernel: [56308.647628] rfkill: input handler enabled
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (**) Option "fd" "61"
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event1  - (II) Power Button: (II) device removed
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (**) Option "fd" "51"
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event0  - (II) Power Button: (II) device removed
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (**) Option "fd" "56"
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event2  - (II) HID 0566:3032: (II) device removed
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (**) Option "fd" "50"
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (**) Option "fd" "58"
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event4  - (II) USB OPTICAL MOUSE : (II) device removed
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (**) Option "fd" "50"
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) event3  - (II) HID 0566:3032: (II) device removed
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:1
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:0
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[19174]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 226:1
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:67
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:64
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:66
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:65
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:68
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 226:0
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio gsd-rfkill[1696]: g_object_notify: object class 'CcRfkillGlib' has no property named 'kernel-noinput'
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio kernel: [56317.354529] rfkill: input handler disabled
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio gnome-software[1902]: running get-distro-updates with refine-flags=require-setup-action with timeout=60 on plugin=appstream took 2ms
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 5906
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz eP)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x400"x70.0   23.35  640 656 720 800  400 401 404 417 -hsync +vsync (29.2 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x72.0   78.43  1024 1080 1192 1360  768 769 772 801 -hsync +vsync (57.7 kHz e)
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) event1  - (II) Power Button: (II) is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) event1  - (II) Power Button: (II) device is a keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) event0  - (II) Power Button: (II) is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) event0  - (II) Power Button: (II) device is a keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) event2  - (II) HID 0566:3032: (II) is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) event2  - (II) HID 0566:3032: (II) device is a keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) event3  - (II) HID 0566:3032: (II) is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) event3  - (II) HID 0566:3032: (II) device is a keyboard
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) event4  - (II) USB OPTICAL MOUSE : (II) is tagged by udev as: Mouse
Nov 30 21:06:58 olimpio /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1308]: (II) event4  - (II) USB OPTICAL MOUSE : (II) device is a pointer
Nov 30 21:06:59 olimpio org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1496]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 73 with keysym 73 (keycode 27).
Nov 30 21:07:05 olimpio org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1496]: message repeated 3 times: [ Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 73 with keysym 73 (keycode 27).]
Nov 30 21:07:08 olimpio firefox[11880]: ../../../../gobject/gsignal.c:3492: signal name 'selection_changed' is invalid for instance '0x7fb5be668740' of type 'MaiAtkType319'
Nov 30 21:07:13 olimpio org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1496]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 73 with keysym 73 (keycode 27).
```

At /var/log/auth.log, nothing important info.
At /var/log/Xorg.0.log, just these lines are important:

```
[ 59118.076] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[ 59437.573] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): EDID vendor "AOC", prod id 5906
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  135.00  1280 1296 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (80.0 kHz eP)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   36.00  800 824 896 1024  600 601 603 625 +hsync +vsync (35.2 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 656 720 840  480 481 484 500 -hsync -vsync (37.5 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   31.50  640 664 704 832  480 489 492 520 -hsync -vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   30.24  640 704 768 864  480 483 486 525 -hsync -vsync (35.0 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   78.75  1024 1040 1136 1312  768 769 772 800 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   75.00  1024 1048 1184 1328  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (56.5 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "832x624"x0.0   57.28  832 864 928 1152  624 625 628 667 -hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   49.50  800 816 896 1056  600 601 604 625 +hsync +vsync (46.9 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   50.00  800 856 976 1040  600 637 643 666 +hsync +vsync (48.1 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "640x400"x70.0   23.35  640 656 720 800  400 401 404 417 -hsync +vsync (29.2 kHz e)
[ 59437.703] (II) RADEON(0): Modeline "1024x768"x72.0   78.43  1024 1080 1192 1360  768 769 772 801 -hsync +vsync (57.7 kHz e)
[ 59437.723] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event1 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 59437.723] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event1 is a keyboard
[ 59437.737] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event0 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 59437.737] (II) input device 'Power Button', /dev/input/event0 is a keyboard
[ 59437.738] (II) input device 'HID 0566:3032', /dev/input/event2 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 59437.738] (II) input device 'HID 0566:3032', /dev/input/event2 is a keyboard
[ 59437.740] (II) input device 'HID 0566:3032', /dev/input/event3 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 59437.740] (II) input device 'HID 0566:3032', /dev/input/event3 is a keyboard
[ 59437.804] (II) input device 'USB OPTICAL MOUSE ', /dev/input/event4 is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[ 59437.804] (II) input device 'USB OPTICAL MOUSE ', /dev/input/event4 is a pointer caps
[ 59437.805] (II) input device 'USB2.0 Camera', /dev/input/event12 is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 59437.805] (II) input device 'USB2.0 Camera', /dev/input/event12 is a keyboard
[ 64934.401] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[ 68655.183] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 68655.884] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 68655.884] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 68655.884] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 68655.884] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 68655.884] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 68655.885] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 68656.310] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Any ideas? Will I have to disable dual GPU?